# Get datepicker value using jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), how can I get the value of the date picker in the http post when it's used like this within a form:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("input[name='something']").val(dateText);
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/9hbmy/338/

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Thanks for the fiddle, made it easier to understand! +1

Answer (score 27):

Are you looking for this.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
```

Comment: Generally I just put stuff in a hidden input like this `<input type="hidden" name="something" value="thevalue" />` and this is posted to the form action. How can I use that but put it in the form?

Answer (score 6):

Init:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-m-dd" });
```

Get value:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().val() //2014-4-15
```

See format settings at:

http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 2):

You should tie the datepicker to a form input instead of a div, so the value in the input will be submitted back with the form.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</sript>
```

Comment: @ing0 If you have restrictions that prevent you from using a text input to capture the date, you'll want to either use the `altField` property to capture the date in a hidden input or provide an `onSelect` callback to do what you need with the selected date as Thorsten and Jen have suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. Went for the onSelect callback.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field and add it to the "[altField](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field)" option should do it.

Edit: You might also want to check out this solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker">KLICK ME</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidde_date_field" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#hidde_date_field').datepicker();

$('#datepicker').click(function() {
    $('#hidde_date_field').datepicker( "show" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me:

```
$("#datepicker").find(".active").attr("data-date")
```