# Jquery Date Time picker show on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello i have a jquery ui date time picker.

And now i want it on a input field showed on page load so it must already been showed without click or focus.

And i also want to make the input field type hidden.

Link to website: [HERE](http://nedwebdesign.nl/minerva/agenda.html)

someone any ideas ? i already search this site and google but cant find anything.

Jquery code

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "nl" ] );

            $('#date').datetimepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: 30,
                timeText: 'Tijd',
                hourText: 'Uur',
                minuteText: 'Minuten',
                secondText: 'Seconden'
            });
```

HTML code

```
<label id="test">test</label><input type="text" value="" id="date" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `$('#date').datepicker('show');` function after you've initialized the datepicker, although I could have sworn there was an option for that.

Comment: Yes but when i hide the input field the datepicker is gone

Comment: That's a problem with jQuery UI. The documentation states specifically "If the datepicker is attached to an input, the input must be visible for the datepicker to be shown."

Comment: mm maby i can try with css visibility:hidden

Comment: i just dont wanna see the input field only the datepicker and after the user set it up it must be emailed to the owner

Comment: Have you considered not using an input and instead just displaying inline? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

Comment: yes but i need to send the information with the post method.
as far as i know u cant send information from a div or something

Comment: Then using JavaScript, you can detect if the user selects a date in the datepicker and then change the "value" field of a hidden input elsewhere on the page.

Comment: okey that will be great. But my knowledge of javescript is not that great :(

Comment: Thhx m8 found a link with that idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667149/get-datepicker-value-using-jqueryui

Comment: so stupid that i dindnt came up with that idea its so simple lol

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take advantage of the display inline and populate alternate field options. It would look something like this:

**HTML**:

```
Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="text" value="" id="date" />
```

**JS**:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "nl" ] );

$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 30,
    timeText: 'Tijd',
    hourText: 'Uur',
    minuteText: 'Minuten',
    secondText: 'Seconden',
    altField: "#date",
    altFormat: "yourDateFormat"
});
```

Comment: awesome this works also but only 1 problem is that it only parse the time and not the date