# How to get datepicker data in jQuery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I get data of a datapicker in jQuery ui?
I've the next code but only get default value. (I use only years)

```
$('#datePickerTempe').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    //To hide months:
    stepMonths: 12,  
    monthNames: ["","","","","","","","","","","",""], 
    //Range
    minDate: '-4y',  //'M'-> month | 'w'-> week | 'd'-> day
    maxDate: '0y',

    buttonImageOnly: true 
});

$('#datePickerTempe').on('click', function(){ 
console.log('año: '+$('#datePickerTempe').val()); });
```

Comment: Using a datepicker to select a year is quite an unusual solution... wouldn't a simple dropdown menu be easier for the user?

Comment: I prefer datepicker because jqueryui combobox doesn't work fine

Comment: Do you know another similar option?

Comment: `<select type="multiple">` is a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Get current date from datepicker (or null if nothing selected):

```
var selectedDate = $('#datePickerTempe').datepicker("getDate");
```

You can also add `onSelect` handler to `datepicker`:

```
$('#datePickerTempe').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        console.log(dateText);
    }
});
```

Refer to [datepicker getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method and [datepicker onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) option

Comment: I think that it doesn't work because the value isn't reloaded if a day is selected. And I don't use days.

Comment: @vicenrele perhaps I don't understand, but value is changing every time you select new date. I have even used your options in my sample and it works, it shows correct date, check [it here](http://jsbin.com/atikay/3/). I think you are asking wrong question, what exacly you are trying to achive?

Comment: Check this out: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/9hbmy/) If you don't select a day, the value doesn't change. It changes when a day is selected. I'll solve the problem using another option without datepicker

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" value=""/>    

<script>
    var date_fields = $('#date');
    date_fields.datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
        date_fields.datepicker('hide');
        date_fields.blur();
    });
</script>
```

The added scripts http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Works perfectly fine here.

Comment: @vicenrele then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667149/get-datepicker-value-using-jqueryui should do it.

Comment: I think that it doesn't work because the value isn't reloaded if a day is selected. And I don't use days.